# How to get an identifier (e.g xpath) from a nokogiri object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xpath, nokogiri

Walking through nokogiri and selecting elements with an xpath is fairly easy. I need the vice versa of this, meaning: I need to e.g. call `.to_xpath` on a nokogiri node to get the full xpath of an element to store it in a record.

Anyone knows a way of doing this?

Comment: XML or HTML? Do all of your nodes have `id` attributes?

Comment: it's html and they don't have any id nodes because there are custom html tags used which gets substituted and multiplied dynamically..

Comment: You probably want to go with Serabe's but I'll leave mine around anyway. Sorry if my tunnel vision made you do more work than necessary.

Comment: thanks anyway for your detailes solution, i like it though. Couldn't find what i needed in the doc's, too :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easiest way I can think off would be:

`Nokogiri::CSS.xpath_for node.css_path`

**EDIT:** you can give `path` method a try too.

Comment: Thank you. Nokogiri's a great library with methods for almost everything you can think of.

Comment: just saw that css_path also will do the trick, this may speed things up. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can think of would be to use [`parent`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-parent) to build an element path back to the root (i.e. back to `<html>`) and [`previous_element`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-previous_element) at each node to figure out the numeric index of that node amongst its siblings. Since there will be exactly one `<body>` and `<html>` (Nokogiri will add these for you behind your back if necessary) you can stop walking up the parents once you hit the `<body>` node.

The algorithm looks like this:

1. Initialization: `path = [ ]`, `n` is the node you already have.
2. Set `s = n` and call `s = s.previous_element` until `s.nil?` and count how many iterations you made, this will give you the position of `n` amongst its siblings. Put the position in `index`. Keep in mind that XPath positions are one-based.
3. Store the new path component: `path.unshift('*[' + index.to_s + ']')`.
4. Set `p = n.parent`, if `p` is not the `<body>` then `n = p` and go back to step 2.
5. Add the final components that we know are there: `path.unshift('body').unshift('html')`.
6. Build the XPath expression: `xpath = '/' + path.join('/')`

So given some HTML like this:

```
<ul><li>a</li><li><b>b<em>c</em></b></li></ul>
```

and a start node of `<em>c</em>`, you'd end up with an XPath like this:

```
/html/body/*[1]/*[2]/*[1]/*[1]
```

Not exactly pretty but at least the process is fairly simple and the resultant XPath will be unique.

If you need paths to most of the nodes in the DOM then you could start at the root and number all the nodes on the way down. That way you could avoid walking the siblings over and over again.

Comment: @pduersteler: You probably want to add a couple tests to make sure you get the 0/1/many siblings numbers right.